# React: fetching data and rendering data but fetch response comes later than component mounting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to display dances that I get from an api call, but I useEffect mounts before api call gets a response so the data doesn't display. What am i doing wrong?

I have posted my code below.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong or how what is the best practice for such cases. I know I could return html from inside the function but I don't think that looks very nice

```
function Home() {
  const userId = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.id);
  const [dances, setDances] = useState<DanceCardProps[]>([])
  interface DanceCardProps {
    picture?: string;
    name: string;
    danceId: string;
    description?: string;
    author: string;
    year?: number;
  }

  const fetchDanceData = async() => {
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_API_URL + "/app/getDances?accountId=1", {
      headers: {EXAMPLE,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res: ", res);
        var newArray = dances as DanceCardProps[]
        res.data.map((obj: DanceCardProps )=> {
          console.log(obj)
          const newDance = {
            danceId: obj.danceId,
            name: obj.name,
            author: obj.author
          }
          newArray.push(newDance)
        })
        setDances(newArray as DanceCardProps[])
        console.log("dances: ",dances)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("error: ", e);
      });
  };


  useEffect(function(){
    fetchDanceData()
  },[dances])

  return (
    <>
      <Stack className={"wrapper"}>
        <FilterRow func={fetchDanceData} />
        <Divider />
        <Grid container spacing={3} className={"home-grid"} direction={"row"}>
          {dances.map((dance: DanceCardProps) => {
            return (
              <DanceCard
                name={dance.name}
                id={dance.danceId}
                author={dance.author}
                year={dance.year}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odu8o.png)

Comment: I'm very surprised that the problem is not getting an infinite loop callback.

Comment: removing "dance" dependency from useEffect wouldn't change anything

Comment: This is how you are supposed to do it:

```useEffect(async ()=>{
    await fetchDanceData()
  },[])```

Also, ```console``` always prints before async functions.

Comment: I tried it but still nothing, but thanks for the input

Comment: If possible please make a codepen link, otherwise, it's just guessing, other than an infinite loop code looks fine. And I assume you don't have an infinite loop because the code doesn't work yet(i.e. dances state doesn't change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const fetchDanceData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_API_URL + "/app/getDances?accountId="+window.sessionStorage.getItem("clientId"),
          {
            headers: {
              rahvatantsukToken: JSON.stringify(
                window.sessionStorage.getItem("rahvatantsukToken")
              )
            },
          }
        );
        const newData = response.data.map((obj: DanceCardProps) => ({
          danceId: obj.danceId,
          name: obj.name,
          author: obj.author,
          year: obj.year,
        }));
        setDances(newData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      }
    };

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchDanceData();
  }, []);
```

So this is what did it for me. Making the response into a variable and awaiting for the response and only then updating the state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).